# what's the correct way to create a typed Observable with RxJS?

Tags: rxjs

I would like to create a custom `Observable` in RxJS 6

The `Observable.create()` method is marked as *deprecated* and it's recommended to use `new Observable()` instead.

This is all fine, but what is the proper way to specify the type of my `Observable`?

```js
myWork() {
  return new Observable( sub => {
    this.target.onsomething = data => {
      sub.next(data);
      sub.complete();
    }
    this.target.onerror = err => sub.error(err);
  });
}
```

The above code returns an `Observable<unknown>`. I have found 2 ways to convert it to what I want, but neither of them feel clean.

**option 1** specify the type in the return function.

```js
myWork(): Observable<MyData> {}
```

**option 2** specify the type of the *subscriber*

```js
return new Observable( (sub: Subscriber<MyData>) => { //...
```

Am I missing a 3rd way that is cleaner?

Comment: Option 1 is what you need

Comment: What the cleanest way is is pretty subjective. I would always specify the return type of a function in Typescript so I think Option 1 is always recommended. I additionally specify the type on an Observable when I create one like this: `new Observable<MyData>(sub => {})`

Answer (score -1):

Just use a subject

```
myWork$ = new Subject<MyData>();
```

and you can call next when you want it to emit

```
update(data: MyData) {
  this.myWork$.next(data);
}
```

Comment: so, the problem I ran into with that is that technically, I call something like `this.target.dosomework()` and _then_ return the `Observable`. When I do that, something is not right. I think it's because the subscriber subscribes potentially after the work completed in some instances. Does that sound right?

Comment: You expose the myWork$ as a property on your service, any subscribers that subscribe to the observable will get notified when do work is called. You don't return the observable from anywhere, it is just exposed as a property.

Comment: Read this article I wrote on making Angular services, it might make things clearer. https://medium.com/@adrianbrand/angular-state-management-with-rxcache-468a865fc3fb

Comment: He doesn't need subject since he want to emit get a stream from some events. He needs observable. Adrian, please, read this article “On The Subject Of Subjects (in RxJS)” by Ben Lesh https://link.medium.com/8zf0LM5tr1

Comment: Hey @AdrianBrand I think @cuddlemeister is correct. Think of what I am trying to do as similar to `HttpClient` and when you make a request, a new `Observable` is created. It's for one-time use kinda of work. I should have had more details probably in my question. Thanks for taking the time.